# mobile / web application for confrence text / photo messaging

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb, mobile, webrtc

Imagine a social network application similar to twitter which every user is following and is also followed by some other users and whenever a user sends a message (text or photo) it is displayed instantly on the screen of users following him/her. What is the best way to make such an application for:

- mobile
- web

I have some web programming experience and the only way I know to do this in web is to send an ajax call every second from a user's client. My feeling tells me there should be a better way. I did some research and found webrtc. Is that the way to go? I (and probably many other users) will be grateful if you can explain the pros and cons of the solution you suggest.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to build conference app/ messaging app for web/mobile platform you can use latest web technologies.

Node.js is an Javascript framework which does efficient and non blocking IO and it works really well with applications which are not data intesive which involve lot of calculations.

Please go through Node.js and libraries associated with it, you can ahieve building efficient chat application.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. What is the difference between Node.js and WebRTC? Isn't WebRTC a newer technology and probably better than Node.js? Thanks.